# How can I send message in Azure event hub directly from browser?

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have to send a message in Azure event hub directly from browser. Is there any library which works purely on browser or do I have to just use [Event Hub service REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/event-hubs-runtime-rest)?

Answer (score 1):

The [@azure/event-hubs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/event-hubs) package supports use on the browser for some scenarios, including publishing events.
[This sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/samples/v5/browser/src/sendEvents.js) covers the send-from-browser details.  The set of all browser-focused samples can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/main/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/samples-browser).